# How can i used nested SUM functions with multiple criteria?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2019

This formula is nearly complete, I am just missing a small part of it that I cannot see!

I want cell `A19` to `SUM` column `K:K` if column `A:A` contains either `OPEN` OR `CLOSED`.

What is it I am missing?

The formula works if only counting `CLOSED` or `OPEN` however I need it to count both.

The current formula in `A19` :

`=IF(COUNT(A9)=1,TEXT(SUMIF('SPREADS LOG'!A:A,("CLOSED"),'SPREADS LOG'!K:K)," £ #,##0.00")&" / "&TEXT(SUM(SUMIF('SPREADS LOG'!A:A,{"CLOSED","OPEN"},'SPREADS LOG'!K:K)," £ #,##0.00"),""))`

Note I need to keep the oddities of `/` in the formula as it is doing two separate calculations and I would like them to be displayed as  `1234 / 5678`

Comment: `TEXT,SUM`??? I think you are missing `()`.

Comment: One time it is worth checking the parts before assembling into one long function.

Comment: Have edited it to ```=IF(COUNT(A9)=1,TEXT(SUMIF('SPREADS LOG'!A:A,("CLOSED"),'SPREADS LOG'!K:K)," £ #,##0.00")&" / "&TEXT(SUM(SUMIF('SPREADS LOG'!A:A,{"CLOSED","OPEN"},'SPREADS LOG'!K:K)," £ #,##0.00"),""))``` however now shows VALUE error, any further advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This not so elegant way worked for me ...

```
=TEXT(SUMIF('SPREADS LOG'!A:A,("CLOSED"),'SPREADS LOG'!K:K)," £ #,##0.00")&
" / "&
TEXT(SUM(
         SUMIF('SPREADS LOG'!A:A,"Open",'SPREADS LOG'!K:K),
         SUMIF('SPREADS LOG'!A:A,"Closed",'SPREADS LOG'!K:K)
         )," £ #,##0.00")
```

Are there values in K other than Open or Closed?  If not, you could replace lines 4 and 5 with `SPREADS LOG'!A:A`.

Assuming that there are other values in K and that you have a 365 subscription, you can use the new LET function to make this formula a bit simpler.

```
=LET(sumRng,'SPREADS LOG'!K:K, lkupRng,'SPREADS LOG'!A:A,
           TEXT(SUMIF(lkupRng,("CLOSED"),sumRng)," £ #,##0.00")
           &" / "&
           TEXT(SUM(
                    SUMIF(lkupRng,"Open",sumRng),
                    SUMIF(lkupRng,"Closed",sumRng)
                   )," £ #,##0.00")
    )
```